# Multiply decision variable with index used in it

Tags: python, gurobi

I am writing an optimization modell in python that I will solve with Gurobi. However I have got one problem with one constraint. 
I want to multiply my decision variable with the index of j: 
`x[i,j] * j` , with `j` as the `index of j` used in `x[i,j]`. 
`i` and `j` are both are modeled as lists. The decisionvariable `x[i,j]` is binary.

I tried with

```
for i in I:
  m.addConstr (x[i,j]*J.index(j))
```

But this will always take the last element of the list j. How can I make the constraint to take in the `index of j` used in `x[i,j]`?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, could you give an example?

Comment: ohh sorry, of course

Comment: so my whole constraint in theory is formulated as: x[i,j]*j <= M*p[i]+z[i]*u[i]. With this soft constraint (x and z are both binary decision varible) I want to check if x[i,j]*j  is smaller than M *p[i], in case it is not z must get one. With x[i,j] *j I want to have an expression that for example x["A","B"] =1 multiplies by the  index of "B" in list of j (for example 2), so that x[i,j] *j =1*2=2. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

if j is integer or continus, you can directly do x[i,j]*j, if not, your code is seem correct. i think that you want to write this :

```
for j in J:
   for i in I:
      m.addConstr(x[i,j]*J.index(j))
```

or

```
for i in I:
   m.addConstr(x[i,j]*J.index(j) for j in J)
```

Can you give détails ?

You can also use range like this:

```
for i in I :
   m.add(x[i,J[k]]*k for k in range(len(J))
```

or

```
for k in range(len(J)):
   for i in I:
       m.addConstr(x[i,J[k]]*k)
```